# Got a keyboard will hide notification, but keyboard was not even present

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I've got this strange warning in my app after pushing view controller which overrides inputAccessoryView like that:

```
lazy var inputView = InputView()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return inputView
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

What can produce this warning?

Comment: Probably it’s related with your keyboard observers, are you registering and removing them correctly?

Comment: I don't have any keyboard observers. Is it true that I don't have to remove them in iOS 11?